# Is it possible to find out what bonuses you're receiving from your designated booster?

Tags: eve-online

I am currently in a fleet where each member has trained a different set of skills that provide boosts to other pilots in the fleet, I have set the 'squad booster' to one member that has the Mining Foreman skill to increase mining yield. When I hover over the 'tick' in the Fleet window, the message simply states "You are receiving bonuses from: Squad Booster":

[image]

Without asking the pilot set with squad booster what abilities they have that influence their fleet's skills, and what levels they're at, is it possible to find out what bonuses you're receiving from your designated booster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no. Longer answer, not practically.

You can always figure out what bonuses they are handing out by jumping out of system, writing down everything that could be affected (or using the in-game notepad), and then jumping back in.

You're getting bonuses, and if the FC is any good, they'll make sure to ask what the bonuses are and post it in fleet chat and/or acknowledge it over voice chat.

Comment: That's a shame, seems like the sort of feature that would be nice to have. Thanks for the answer though!